# ODE solver for stiff and non-linear differential equations

Tags: matlab, ode

I have to solve a stiff non-linear differential equation. I tried ode45,ode15s and ode23s amongst MATLAB solvers, none of them has worked. Program is stuck in busy state after some steps at ode-solvers line in program. Any help will be appreciated.

This is an example from code.

I would like to solve a boundary value problem with newtons method.

this is `main.m`

```
for i=1:10 %convergence criteria
[FF,JJ,F2,J2]=newton(s,tm,m);

% newtons method with F and J
 delta_s=-F2'*inv(J2')';
 delta_s=reshape(delta_s,11,2);
 s(:,1:2) = s(:,1:2) + delta_s; % in straight newton t=1
 %%%%%   

if norm(delta_s)<tol
    break
end

end
```

When i debug the code it is stuck in line with ode15s. s variables are solutions here with each interval.

```
function [FF,JJ,F2,J2] = newton(s,tm,m)
lambda = 1e9;
F = zeros(2*m, 1);
J2=zeros(2*m,size(s,1));
G0=eye(2,2);
for l=1:m-1

    y0=[s(l,1:2)';G0(:)];

     f=@(t,y)odes(t,y);
     opts=odeset('RelTol',1e-6,'Stats','on'); 
     sols=ode15s(f,[tm(l),tm(l+1)],y0,opts); 

end
```

Comment: [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example of the code?

Comment: Thanks for reply. I added the code example in question.

Comment: Your code isn't runnable. The issue is likely with in your `odes` function. Please provide a minimal runnable example. This means get rid of the `for` loop (which specific loop values and parameter cause the issue) and the `main` function.

Comment: I have figured out why i have busy state when i run the code. 
in newton function y0 causes the problem. If i give the value of y0 explicitly like [ a b]  instead of y0  in ode15s, program just works fine. I do not understand why it requires that.